# Unity Game Assets with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

for a course at my university I am building a small engine with C++, using the OpenGL API. Since I need some 3D models for my characters I'd like to know if it is possible to make use of the sets without having unity installed. I would like to import the FBX files into Maya or another 3D modeling package and then export it as obj sequence which I read into OpenGL as individual VBOs for the animation. I know this technique is outdated but that is not the point here. Since this ( https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/68910 ) is a whole kit which is highly customizable I highly doubt that it is  convenient to use with any other software than unity.

Answer (score 1):

Use an asset importing library like [ASSIMP](http://www.assimp.org/) so your OpenGL application can directly load the FBX files. Converting poses into static meshes is just impractical and would just be harder to manage than writing a skeletal animation module for your application.